# Angular JS route causing infinite loop

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out why the page doesn't navigate to its template when clicked. The URL updates, and I have no JS errors.. I believe it *loads* the file, but then it infinitely loads the controller. I found this out after I put a `console.log('test!')` in my SessionsController's instantiation.

**The layout**

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

**My View**

```
<a href="/testing"> My link of seriousness </a>
```

**My JS**

```
window.MainController = function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
  $scope.$route = $route;
  $scope.$location = $location;
  $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
  console.log($route);
  console.log($location);
  console.log($routeParams);
};

MainController.$inject = ["$scope", "$route"];

window.app = angular.module('web_client', [], function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  return $routeProvider.when('/testing', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/other_stuff/index.html',
    controller: 'MyController'
  });
});


window.MyController = function($scope, $http) {
  console.log('Infinite Loop!');
};
```

And in `partials/sessions/new.html` , I have big and bright :

```
FOOBAR!
```

Comment: @npm I'm not sure what you mean. What is the "/" routes definition that I'm missing, and where would you place that?

Comment: Can you create http://jsfiddle.net/ example to illustrate issue? There you can even add your coffeescript code - sometimes it produce quite unexpected js.

Comment: I think this must be an implementation error. Maybe I'm not thinking about this correctly? I just want the view `sessions/new.html` to show as the view when clicking on my link.. Perhaps I'm doing something else? I updated my answer, but jsfiddle won't work appropriately unless I have my views, controllers, routes, everything up there and then translated to javascript. I'm definitely sure there's no js errors at all.

Comment: A few things... it's completely unnecessary to sculpt your view in something the server will have to process everytime. Ember, Meteor and Angular should be processing all HTML for you, anything the server his hosting up you should be able to hard code and cache. Also it's my personal belief that using CoffeeScript in a framework you're unfamiliar with is asking for trouble. Those two things aren't directly related to the cause of your problems, but they are going to hinder you when trying to debug it.

Comment: Its all just html. Server isn't doing anything but hosting a static site.

Comment: And don't worry about coffeescript. There's no JS errors. :D

Comment: You are limiting potential answers by assuming everybody can read either coffeescript or whatever serverside template engine you are using without using the proper tags in the OP,for me it is gibberish. Is your "bug" reproducible ? then you should provide all the relevant code. that's what fiddles are for.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll try and be more universal in my code submission. I updated my code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I see are missing brackets and a missing comma. You may try with this:

```
$routeProvider
  .when("/login", {
    templateUrl: "sessions/new.html",
    controller: SessionsController
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/"
  });
```

Comment: Oh sorry its coffeescript, so no commas needed. But how come when my browser displays `#/login`, it doesnt' actually change the page? Its still the same page..

Comment: I checked my implementation and it looks exactly like yours. But does anything load at all?

Comment: No.. perhaps I need a redirectTo: in my `when` statement?

Comment: Are you working with the html5mode or basic hash bang? I am not sure whether this causes your issue but one never knows. If not why not set up a simple fiddle to illustrate your problem.

Comment: I'll take whatever I can get, html5 or not. Just want it to navigate to a url :D . I got a little bit further. Managed to make it go into a recursive loop.. Updated my answer above.. Thanks so much for all your help Flek!

Comment: Okay one last idea: have you tried without the hashbang in the link? So just href="/login"? You also don't need ng-href for that :)

Comment: annnnnnnddd... yes I tried that. Also tried doing a regular link. If I goto the link manually, I go inside the loop, and it keeps instantiating my controllers. The entire library over and over again. If I don't specify a template or a controller in my routes, then the loop is prevented ( but of course no content loads either )..

Comment: Also, I tried extracting an absolute URL for a template outside of my app that is just a text word. And the bug persists with it reloading the entire app over and over again. So that makes me understand that this functionality of reloading the app, or looping through the controllers is done regardless of ng-view's function of instantiating partials, but will only occur if I have an ng-view present.

Comment: Which version of angular do you use? I quickly searched for your problem on google and found some similar problems like yours which had been reported as bugs. Sorry for not having a good solution :)

Comment: 1.0.3 min. I have looked at *all* the related bugs. Maybe all the bugs in general? :D Also I narrowed it down to what its actually loading. It's loading `all.js` every 200ms..

Comment: I resolved this.. and it was for something completely unrelated but sort of related. Just wanted to give thanks for your help. The problem was because I was using middleman to build my app. And you have to specify that partials do not include layout. So when Angular called the partial, it called the entire app again. ( embaressing_face.gif )

Answer (score 10):

I have had this same issue before as well and I think the root cause is the use of `<ng-view>` which it looks like was used in this case as well. The route will already load a template URL so I believe the use of the ng-view directive causes that template to get loaded recursively causing an infinite loop.

Try removing ng-view and instead either place all view markup directly in the .html template you specify in templateUrl of the route.  Alternatively, if it is a shared template try using ng-include instead(e.g. `<div ng-include src="'/path/to/template.html'"></div>`   Don't forget the single quotes around your path to identify it as a string as opposed to a scope variable reference!).

Comment: Thanks for this!  I had used "ng-view" when I had *meant* to use "ng-show".

Answer (score 6):

**Problem with Same Symptoms**

I recently solved a similar problem in one of my projects. I added console.log("Video Page Controller Loaded") into the controller I was debugging. Likewise, it logged that text until I close the tab.

**My solution:**

I was referenced the wrong name for the template file.

```
when('/videos', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/video-list.tpl.html',
  controller: 'VideoListCtrl'
})
```

When I should have had:

```
when('/videos', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/video-list.html',
  controller: 'VideoListCtrl'
})
```

Comment: Just had the same issue. I just needed a "/" in front of my templateUrl which caused the controller to be called infinity. So be have attention to the templateUrl strings.

Comment: I was developing a new feature in an app and I hadn't still created the html template, that's how I got the infinite loop. It seems like Angular is trying to get the page again and again instead of displaying an error (ie: template not found). So yeah, misspelled templateUrl, missing template file and similar can cause this.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same "infinite reload" problem and Alex Johnson made me think. Indeed, if the path of templateURL is empty (this was my case) or wrong path, an infinite reload of resources will happen.
For me the solution was simple: I **replaced `templateURL: ''` with `template: ''`**.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @ArnaudRinquin: When pattern-matching for "same problem", it's best to check if the post also contains a suggested solution. Which this one does.

Comment: Also, why include an empty template?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and ultimately realized I had not actually created the partial html file that I was telling it to load in my app.config - if it can't find the template file, Angular seems to go into an infinite loop of the controller function.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check partial view path is the correct (check if you are getting HTTP code 302 for partial view. You can use morgan with Node+Express to print HTTP code for each request)

   2. If path is correct then you still may be getting infinite loop as Browser cache the static data. You can disable caching in chrome. To do so:

      - Open developer console
      - Click on setting button in developer console
      - Check on option "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)"
      - Restart the server and refresh the page with developer console in open state

For me, problem solved after resolving the path issue and disabling the caching

Answer (score 1):

My problem was with a template URL which was incorrect, and then started triggering a route that matched the URL pattern. Double check your `templateUrl` path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Got the similar problem with Rack application.
Solution was:

```
use Rack::Static, urls: ["/js", "/css", "/templates"]
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was related on specifying the templateUrl without initial "/" not only on my router but on my directives!!