# AngularJS Partial Not Loading

Tags: angularjs

Writing a very simple angular js app to learn routes and partials. The problem is that my  would just not load the partial template at all.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="website">
<head>
    <title>Hello World, AngularJS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/website.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='/login'>Login</a></li>
        <li><a href='/about'>About</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

website.js

```
angular.module('website', ['ngRoute']).
config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/about', {templateUrl: 'partials/about.html'}).
        when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html'}).
        otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
});
```

When I load index.html, it shows the links. When I click on one of the them, or go manually to #/about, it should load the contents of the template inside ng-view, but it doesn't.

The about.html and login.html are just two files with a single

tag in them with Hello World text. What am I missing? I was earlier not including angular-route.js, but fixing that didn't work.

My directory structure goes like this:

```
views
  --js
    --website.js
  --views
    --index.html
    --partials
      --about.html
      --login.html
```

The network says that it did GET about, but brings me back to index.html without anything in ng-view

Comment: So, where are these partials located? What does your browser console say? In the network panel, do you see a request loading trying to load the partial? What's the response? If index.html is at the root, how could it point to a file `../js/website.js`? Have you at least checked that your js file was loaded and your angular application was started? Why are you learning angularJS with an obsolete version?

Comment: I might have been looking at an older tutorial. I updated the version to 1.2.25

Comment: It seems that the js file was not loading at all. If I bring the contents inline to the html file, going to any route crashes the app! And I can now see the network to actually loading partials/about.html

Comment: How about changing `href='/about'` to `href='#/about'` (`#` is missing) ?

Comment: Thanks Lokesh, but no use..

Comment: I put a log in my controller and saw that it gets initialized infinitely thereby causing the crash. This thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565841/angular-js-route-causing-infinite-loop says that the solution is to specify that partials dont include layout. But I cant figure out how to do that